# Jenkins auto-prepends PATH with path to java and ant. How to disable?

Tags: jenkins

In a Free-form project I use "Inject environment variables":

```
JAVA_HOME=/u01/jenkins/jdk1.8.0_181/jre
PATH=/u01/jenkins/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/bin:/u01/jenkins/apache-maven-3.0.5/bin:${PATH}
```

However, in shell scripts `$PATH` gets an additional prefix:

```
++ echo PATH=/u01/jenkins/jdk1.7.0_55/bin:\
    /u01/jenkins/apache-ant-1.9.6/bin:/u01/jenkins/apache-maven-3.0.5/bin:\
    /u01/jenkins/DependencyFinder-1.2.1-beta4/bin:\
    /bin:/u01/jenkins/fly:/u01/jenkins/jdk1.7.0_55/bin:\
    /u01/jenkins/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/bin:<the-original-path>
```

How to find what's causing it and finally have my java 8 in path?

**Upd**: all entries except `/u01/jenkins/jdk1.7.0_55/bin` were being added by `jenkins_shell` script. This is now fixed. But I still don't know who's adding the first entry - path to java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a JDK is configured in `Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration` then a global environment variable is created: `PATH+JDK=/u01/jenkins/jdk1.7.0_55/bin` and right before the execution of shell scripts Jenkins prepends `PATH` with `PATH+JDK` (actually, any variable that starts with "PATH+"

https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/c904989067aa699ea63d043c44f6ea905cb9c5d5/core/src/main/java/hudson/EnvVars.java#L144

The workaround is to inject an empty `PATH+JDK=` variable to disable the prepending completely or to inject `PATH+JDK=/path/to/proper/jdk`.

Additionally, since `EnvVars extends TreeMap` you can inject another variable: `PATH+ZZZ=/path/to/something` which is prepended later than `PATH+JDK` because Jenkins iterates such vars in alphabetic order.

Finally, it's possible to configure a dummy JDK without executables and select this dummy JDK in a dropdown in the Job.